# Robot keypress not working in headless mode

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, headless-browser

Could like to press character 'v' in keyboard through robot which works fine as expected in browser mode but not working in headless mode .

Trying to loop throught list of elements and screenshot it post keypress . I am using Robot class to press the character 'v' which is not working instead it prints v in output.

I am using firefox- geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64 driver and my browser version is v69.0.1 .

```
        List<WebElement> eleq = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".class"));
        JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
        for(WebElement e: eleq){
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", e);
            Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
            Action seriesOfActions = builder
                    .moveToElement(e)
                    .build();
            seriesOfActions.perform();
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V); 
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Date d =new Date();
            File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File(d.toString().replace(":", "_")+".png"));
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        }
```

Could like to know if there are any alternatives to keypress in Java selenium apart from Robot since most of my search led to Robot not working in headless.

Answer (score 1):

Of-course it will not as Robot do the event without seen any other dependency.

Even if you minimize the your automation browser screen it won't work as it is independent from everything

That's why using Robot is not recommended in automation.

You need to identify other way to complete your step

you can do something like below:

```
String selectAll = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a");
driver.findElement(By.id("your locator")).sendKeys(selectAll);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this using Actions in selenium.